# animation error just after adding paging3 dependency

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl, android-paging-3, jetpack-compose-navigation

Just after adding Paging 3 dependency in module level build.gradle.kts, I encountered a runtime error with the following message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentTransitionScopeImpl cannot be cast to androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentScope
```

Here are the versions of the dependencies I'm using that might be relevant:

Compose version: 1.2
Kotlin version: 1.7
Paging Compose version: 3.3.0-alpha03
Paging runtime version: 3.2.1
Navigation version: 2.3.5
Navigation compose version: 2.4.2

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with Paging 3 ?
Any insights or suggestions for resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!